# how to know that locationManager has stopped updating location in ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I know that `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` used to stop updating location. But when you fire this method, the locationManager does not stop immediately after executing this code. Its keeps firing the delegate method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` until it gets a proper location. So, how do I know that locationManager has stopped completely? Because after completing location updates I need to fire some certain method which must be called after locationManager stops.

Comment: if you don't want to call delegate method agin then you should write that after stop updating  self.locationManager = nil;

Comment: @MikeAlter : I did but setting locationManager to nil immediately after `stopUpdatingLocation` does not give me exact location. It gives me cached location everytime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930850/when-should-i-stop-updating-location-manager